# Вращение графика вокруг начала координат

Tags: c++, qt, математика, графика

Может кто помочь сделать вращающийся график? приложение написано на С++ Qt.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <cfloat>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

// Функция 1
double function_1(double x)
{
    return x;
}

// Функция 2
double function_2(double x)
{
    return x * x;
}

// Структура привязки CheckBox-а к функции
class SelectFunction
{
public:
    SelectFunction(QCheckBox *cb, double (*funct)(double)) : checkBox(cb), function(funct) {}
    const QCheckBox* getCheck() { return checkBox; }
    double (* getFunction())(double) { return function; }

private:
    QCheckBox *checkBox;      // указатель на CheckBox
    double (*function)(double); // указатель на функцию
};

void MainWindow::on_buttonDrawCharts_clicked()
{
    layout=new QVBoxLayout();
    std::vector<SelectFunction> checksFunct;
    checksFunct.push_back(SelectFunction(ui->checkFunc_1, function_1));
    checksFunct.push_back(SelectFunction(ui->checkFunc_2, function_2));



    bool ok_a, ok_b, ok_h;
    double a = ui->lineEdit_a->text().toDouble(&ok_a);
    double b = ui->lineEdit_b->text().toDouble(&ok_b);
    double h = ui->lineEdit_h->text().toDouble(&ok_h);

    if (!ok_a || !ok_b || !ok_h) {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText("Некорректно заданы входные параметры.");
        msgBox.exec();
        return;
    }

    double minY = DBL_MAX, maxY = DBL_MIN;
    // Определяем количество точек
    int n = (b - a) / h + 2;

    if (n != 0) {
        // Очищаем все графики
        ui->widgetCharts->clearGraphs();
        // Подписываем оси Ox и Oy
        ui->widgetCharts->xAxis->setLabel("X");
        ui->widgetCharts->yAxis->setLabel("Y");

        size_t number_charts = 0;
        // Цикл, по всем функциям
        for (size_t i = 0; i < checksFunct.size(); ++i) {
            if (checksFunct[i].getCheck()->isChecked()) {               // если установлен CheckBox
                QVector<double> points_x(n), points_y(n);
                double x = a;                                           // задаем начальное значение x
                double (*funct)(double) = checksFunct[i].getFunction(); // определяем функцию
                // Цикл по всему интервалу, с заданным шагом
                for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j, x += h) {
                    points_x[j] = x;
                    points_y[j] = funct(x);
                    // Определяем максимальное и минимальное значение по оси Oy
                    if (points_y[j] < minY)
                        minY = points_y[j];
                    if (points_y[j] > maxY)
                        maxY = points_y[j];
                }
                // Добавляем один график в widgetCharts
                ui->widgetCharts->addGraph();
                // Задаем график для отрисовnumbersки
                ui->widgetCharts->graph(number_charts)->setData(points_x, points_y);
                // Задаем тип точек
                ui->widgetCharts->graph(number_charts)->setScatterStyle(QCPScatterStyle(QCPScatterStyle::ssDisc, 3));
                // Увеличиваем количество выводимых графиков
                ++number_charts;
            }
        }

        // Установим область, которая будет показываться на графике
        ui->widgetCharts->xAxis->setRange(a, b);        // для оси Ox
        ui->widgetCharts->yAxis->setRange(minY, maxY);  // для оси Oy

        connect(sl,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),this,SLOT(mov()));
        // Устанавливаем возможность масштабирвания графиков
        ui->widgetCharts->setInteraction(QCP::iRangeZoom, true);
        // Устанавливаем возможность перетаскивания графиков
        ui->widgetCharts->setInteraction(QCP::iRangeDrag, true);

        // Перерисуем график на нашем widgetCharts
        ui->widgetCharts->replot();
    }
}


    void MainWindow::mov() {

            QPainterPath temp1(QPointF(x_res*300,y_res*300));
            for(double i=0; i>=-y_res*sqrt(6500); i-=x_res*3) {
                double x = cos(2*3.1415926535897932384626433832795*2*(sl->value()-49)/100);
                double y = sin(2*3.1415926535897932384626433832795*2*(sl->value()-49)/100);
                temp1.lineTo(x_res*(300+i*x+i*i*y*0.05),y_res*(300-(i*i*x*0.05-i*y)));
            }
            temp1.moveTo(x_res*300,y_res*300);
            for(double i=0; i<y_res*sqrt(6500); i+=x_res*3) {
                double x = cos(2*3.1415926535897932384626433832795*2*(sl->value()-49)/100);
                double y = sin(2*3.1415926535897932384626433832795*2*(sl->value()-49)/100);
                temp1.lineTo(x_res*(300+i*x+i*i*y*0.05),y_res*(300-(i*i*x*0.05-i*y)));
            }

            QPainterPath temp2(QPointF(x_res*300,y_res*300));
            for(double i=0; i<y_res*300; i+=x_res*3) {
                double x = cos(2*3.1415926535897932384626433832795*2*(sl->value()-49)/100);
                double y = sin(2*3.1415926535897932384626433832795*2*(sl->value()-49)/100);
                temp2.lineTo(x_res*(300+i*x+i*y),y_res*(300-(i*x-i*y)));
            }
            temp2.moveTo(x_res*300,y_res*300);
            for(double i=0; i>=-y_res*300; i-=x_res*3) {
                double x = cos(2*3.1415926535897932384626433832795*2*(sl->value()-49)/100);
                double y = sin(2*3.1415926535897932384626433832795*2*(sl->value()-49)/100);
                temp2.lineTo(x_res*(300+i*x+i*y),y_res*(300-(i*x-i*y)));
            }

            scene->removeItem(path1);
            scene->removeItem(path2);

            path1 = new QGraphicsPathItem(temp1);
            path1->setPos(0,0);
            path1->setPen(QPen(Qt::blue));

            path2 = new QGraphicsPathItem(temp2);
            path2->setPos(0,0);
            path2->setPen(QPen(Qt::red));

            scene->addItem(path1);
            scene->addItem(path2);

            scene->setSceneRect(x_res*0,y_res*0,x_res*600,y_res*600);
            view->setScene(scene);



}
```

Comment: Что такое в вашем понимании "вращающийся график"?

Comment: Как двумерную вращающуюся вокруг начала координат фигуру

Comment: Всеравно непонятно. Можете проиллюстрировать?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Нужно чтобы график вращался на несколько градусов за раз( например по таймеру или функция сама на себя) или как вариант по щелчку только уже больше поворот

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужно повернуть точку (или точки) вокруг оси координат на некоторый угол `angle` (в градусах), то можете применить к ним вращение следующим образом:

```
  newX = Cos(angle / 180.0 * pi) * X + Sin(angle / 180.0 * pi) * Y;
  newY = Cos(angle / 180.0 * pi) * Y - Sin(angle / 180.0 * pi) * X;
```

*Обратите внимание, что `newY` использует для расчета `X`, поэтому надо использовать новые переменные для новых значений - `newX` и `newY`.*

Comment: можете еще подсказать как привязать это изменение по scroling (при движении ползунка )или таймеру

Comment: @Salvador с событиями в Qt не знаком, к сожалению.